# Transaction Isolation level needed to avoid missing AUTO_INCREMENT rows in a series of reads?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

If I have the following table (using innodb on cloud SQL)

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
  key VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  payload VARBINARY NOT NULL,
  id LONGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  INDEX (id)
);
```

And I want to perform the following query periodically:

```sql
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE id >= <num>
```

Where `num` starts at 0 and is then set to one more than the last id read in the previous query,  would the default `REPEATABLE READ` transaction isolation level be sufficient to ensure all sequence numbers that are not overwritten are eventually read (i.e. no rows with lower `id` values will ever be added to the table in the future)? Or would the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level need to be used?

Specifically, is the following sequence of events possible under `REPEATABLE READ` using `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2` (the defaults):

1. User A starts write for id 100
2. User B starts write for id 101
3. User B commits write for id 101
4. User C reads a snapshot containing id 101, but not id 100
5. User A commits write for id 100

Comment: `SELECT` queries don't add rows to any table. I think there is a part of this scenario you haven't described yet. Like what are you going to do with the data after you SELECT it?

Comment: That said, any isolation level would work to read all `id` values _eventually_. You would just have to start the transaction for the `SELECT` some time after other queries that inserted rows have committed.

Comment: I don't think the above is missing anything. Note that this is specifically about a sequence of queries spaced over time, where query N only reads ids greater than the largest returned from query N-1. You should assume that there are ongoing writes at any point interleaved or concurrent with any of these queries.

Comment: @DanielCollins posted an answer Is it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're asking. You're wondering if you can block future INSERTs from inserting values in any gaps in the sequence.

If the inserts use the AUTO_INCREMENT mechanism of that table, they will never insert values less than the current max. That's the way AUTO_INCREMENT works.

So clients would need to override the AUTO_INCREMENT, and specify their own id value   instead, designed to insert into a gap where an id value is unused.

There's no isolation level that will block this. I mean, you can't be locking the table forever, right? Some client could insert into the table while your SELECT is not running.

Comment: Not quite. I'm wondering whether, when using innodb and the `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2` (the default), you can have the following scenario happen:


1. User A starts write for id 100

2. User B starts write for id 101

3. User B commits write for id 101

4. User C reads a snapshot containing id 101, but not id 100

5. User A commits write for id 100


In this scenario, using the above read pattern, User C would never read row 100, if it is possible for them to get a snapshot which includes 101 but not 100 in a given read mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, You have created a table using innodb on cloud SQL, and want to perform a particular query to ensure all sequence numbers that are not overwritten are eventually read and you are  concerned about the transaction level whether the REPEATABLE READ will be  enough or  the SERIALIZABLE Isolation level  is needed.

REPEATABLE READ is not enough,  SERIALIZABLE Transaction Isolation Level is more suitable for this scenario as  mentioned below:

Problem  with the Events that are possible under REPEATABLE READ using innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2 (the defaults):

1. User A starts write for id 100
2. User B starts write for id 101
3. User B commits to write for id 101.
4. When User C arrives it will be able to read the snapshots of the last transaction which is here 101 but it won't be able to  read id 100 as the Write operation is still not committed.
5. User A now commits the transaction as every operation has to be committed in order to maintain the Isolation property.(as this could be a problem in the case of REPEATABLE READ as once a write operation is performed an user can come and change the operation anytime).

Solution for the Events that are possible under SERIALIZABLE using innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 2 (the defaults):

1. User A starts Write for id 100, once done it can’t read or write again.
2. User B starts Write for id 101, once done it can’t read or write again.
3. User C reads a snapshot containing id 100, id 101 as no further action performed by the user A and user B.
4. So this method basically ensures that all sequence numbers that are not overwritten are eventually read as it blocks the further read and write.